# How can i tell the 2's complement of a number just by seeing it?

Tags: bit-manipulation, computer-science

I know that there is a shortcut for this,but i'm unable to recollect it now.suppose if we have a binary number as 100100 then we can just tell the 2's complement just with a glance?if you have idea,please share.I vaguely remember that it says something like "scan the binary number from right to left and until u encounter a one just write the 1's, as soon as you encounter one, then the complement the numbers befor that 1."

Thank you for help.

Comment: "2's compliment" is when the number 2 tells you that you are a good programmer. The word you are looking for is "complement".

Answer (score 1):

Complement the number (invert the bits) and add 1.

Comment: I know this, but no need to even do that, just with a glance you can tell, even for a lenghty binary number.

Comment: That *is* “at a glance”. What you were referring to in your question sounds a lot like sign extension by the way, but converting zeroes to ones is pretty trivial.